# meaning of "send something to the devil"

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does "send something to the devil" mean?

Here is an example:

> If you knew what I know, you could send all your worries to the devil.

I wasn't able to find it in dictionaries, though there is the idiom "[go to the devil](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20to%20the%20devil)".

Seems to me that it means *get rid of something annoying*.

Comment: I think it means the same thing. If the listener knew what the speaker knows, then he wouldn't have anything to be worried about.

Answer (score 1):

**"To go to the devil"** is not really usual in English, while it is the "de facto" way of saying it in other languages.

Having *exactly* the same meaning, in English you would use: **"to go to hell"**.

Depending on context, you can replace **"to go"** with **"to send"**.

---

Therefore, the meaning of:

> If you knew what I know, you could **send** all your worries **to the devil**.

will actually be:

> If you knew what I know, you could completely ignore / forget all your worries, as they are actually irrelevant, by comparison.